# Kafka Confluent - Issue with Audit Log Configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, audit-logging

I am using Kafka Confluent platform 7.5.0 on-premises, hosted on a Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS VM.
**My goal is to capture all PRODUCE events and write them to the topic confluent-audit-log-events_produce.**
I have followed the instructions outlined in the [Confluent Documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/audit-logs/audit-logs-properties-config.html#configure-audit-logs-using-the-properties-file)

Here are the configurations I added to the **server.properties** file, according to the documentation:

```
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
authorizer.class.name=io.confluent.kafka.security.authorizer.ConfluentServerAuthorizer

confluent.security.event.logger.enable=true

confluent.security.event.router.config= \
{ \
  "destinations": { \
    "bootstrap_servers": ["host_name:29092"], \
    "topics": { \
      "confluent-audit-log-events": { \
        "retention_ms": 2592000000 \
      }, \
      "confluent-audit-log-events_produce": { \
        "retention_ms": 2592000000 \
      } \
    } \
  }, \
  "default_topics": { \
    "allowed": "confluent-audit-log-events", \
    "denied": "confluent-audit-log-events" \
  }, \
  "routes": { \
    "crn:///kafka=*/group=*": { \
      "produce": { \
        "allowed": "confluent-audit-log-events_produce", \
        "denied": "" \
      } \
    } \
  } \
}
```

I start the Kafka Server using the command
`bin/kafka-server-start etc/kafka/server.properties`, and it starts and runs fine without any errors on `host_name:29092`.

Next, using my custom Producer, I publish data to a topic on this Kafka Server, let's say user-topic. The data is successfully published to this topic.
**However, I expect the PRODUCE event to be logged to the topic confluent-audit-log-events_produce as configured above, but this topic remains empty.**

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

- Checked Kafka server logs for errors or warnings related to the audit log configuration. Found no obvious issues.
- Googled and attempted different configurations without success.

**Could someone please help me understand what might be wrong with my configuration and how to properly set up the audit log for PRODUCE events?**
I appreciate any guidance.